# Stream Notification for EWS Java API

Tags: java, exchangewebservices

I am building an application using `EWS Java API` where I need to get emails from different mailboxes that reside in same **domain/Exchange server**.

I want to use stream notifications for the same and each mailbox will have 1 subscription associated with it.

Do I need to get a different connection (`StreamingSubscriptionConnection`) associated with each mailbox? Or only 1 connection with all the mailboxes' subscriptions added in it will work for me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read:https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be looking to implement affinity see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-maintain-affinity-between-group-of-subscriptions-and-mailbox-server then you group the mailboxes with the same grouping information in the same connection (up to a max of 200 mailboxes per connection). You can't group mailboxes that don't share the same grouping info in the same connection.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just curious as to why mailboxes on same domain and having same exchange URL will have different grouping information ?

Comment: Load balancing, same URL but potentially many different back-end servers servicing the Mailboxes (in the case of Office365 different datacenters). If its just one server then you'll have one group but as environments scale etc.

Comment: Is there any link that I can follow to apply affinity for stream notifications using EWS java API ?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-maintain-affinity-between-group-of-subscriptions-and-mailbox-server contains examples for XML. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, these are shared mailboxes that I am accessing through my account credentials. Will affinity change for shared mailboxes?

Comment: Treat Shared Mailboxes the same as you would any other mailbox, there a good c# sample https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeamsgdev/2013/04/16/ews-streaming-notification-sample/ which you should be able to convert with out to much trouble.